How can I write and handle mixed character states with Python?
everyone,
I am creating a dataset containing many animal species, and there are some species that possess multiple character states for a single feature.
To give an example, I could have "Species_1" with two values in the "Habitat Type" feature, i.e. both 0 and 1.
In the matrices of Nexus type files (used for phylogenetic analysis) these states can be written like: "0/1" or "0&1", I don't know if it is possible to make a similar scoring method for .csv files.
How can I write such a thing in a dataset in .csv format?
Thanks in advance!
One thing that had occurred to me is to create a pair of rows with the same data for each species with mixed state and change only that value in both rows. However, I don't know if this is a common practice and if it might have a negative impact on the calculations, since I would like to analyze the dataset with regressions.
This is a sample from my current dataset (I'm creating it with Excel):



Species
Habitat Type
Habitat Type Score




Sp_1
savannah
0


Sp_2
forest
1


Sp_3
savannah and forest
0&1




Welcome to SO. You need to [edit] and share the code you've written so far or at least a sample of your Nexus and expected CSV data. As to your question "How can I write such a thing in a dataset in .csv format?" - CSV is just text... you can just write it like you describe. You only need to account for the OR operation when interpreting your data.

@Friedrich thank you very much for your reply! I have provided an example of what I am trying to do. I didn't quite understand the "OR operation" thing, is there a precise method to handle this type of value encoding?

structured data belongs in a database or json file as opposed to a single CSV file...

...also, the score should be a single number (ie. the average or sum of 2 numbers).

finally,  this is categorical data rather than numeric, so a regression would not make sense (statistics issue, not really a python coding problem).

I was referring to logical OR. For your case, you'll have to code something to handle it. Something like '0&1'.split('&') might be a start

@D.L Thanks for the answer. Regarding regressions you are right, it is probably better to use classification algorithms. Scoring with average values sounds reasonable to me, thanks!
